# numpy histogram2d produces strange result

Tags: python, numpy, histogram

I am trying to use the numpy `histogram2d` function. I am generating some random data as follows:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
img = np.random.uniform(low=2.0, high=65.0, size=(400, 400))
```

So, the data is between 0 and 65. I have my own hostogram function which produces the desired result as follows:

```
def compute_histogram2d(r, w, bins):
    jh = np.zeros(bins)
    jh_flat = jh.ravel(order='K')

    ref_data = r.ravel(order='K')
    war_data = w.ravel(order='K')

    num_nodes = r.shape[0] * r.shape[1]

    for i in range(num_nodes):
        index = (int(ref_data[i]) + (int)(war_data[i]) * bins[0])
        jh_flat[index] += 1.0

    return jh
```

So, I am casting the values to integer and then incrementing the value in the histogram.

I can call this as to compute a diagonal histogram.

```
jh = compute_histogram2d(img, img, (68, 68))
```

I am trying to get the same result with the numpy histogram2D. So, I do the following:

```
jh2 = np.histogram2d(np.trunc(img.ravel(order='K')).astype(np.int32),
                 np.trunc(img.ravel(order='K')).astype(np.int32),
                 bins=(bins, bins))[0]
```

Here are the first few entries in both these histograms (first column is my own function and second is numpy). These are printed as:

```
for i in range(68):
    print (jh[i, i], jh2[i, i])


0.0      2522.0
0.0      2507.0
2522.0   2558.0
2507.0   2615.0
2558.0   2555.0
2615.0   2519.0
2555.0   2627.0
2519.0   2551.0
2627.0   2585.0
2551.0   2490.0
2585.0   2531.0
2490.0   0.0    <---- Some zeros appear
2531.0   2528.0
2528.0   2557.0
2557.0   2493.0
2493.0   2509.0
2509.0   2608.0
2608.0   2516.0
```

So as you can see the numpy column seems shifted. The values range between 2 and 65. So in my own implementation, the first two values are 0.0 which is correct but the numpy implementation produces non-zero values for `(0, 0)` and `(1, 1)`. Additionally, some zeros appear on the diagonals as well which it should not be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I need to specify the `range` parameter as otherwise things get truncated as outliers.

so use as:

```
jh2 = np.histogram2d(np.trunc(img.ravel(order='K')).astype(np.int32),
                     np.trunc(img.ravel(order='K')).astype(np.int32),
                     bins=(bins, bins),
                     range=[[0, bins], [0, bins]])[0]
```